# Determine if IDP initiated or SP initiated in SP callback?

Tags: passport.js, saml, saml-2.0, passport-saml

I am using passport-saml authentication module in my node application.  In the registered IDP callback function that resides in my SP I need to determine if the callback was SP initiated or IDP initiated.

Does SAML have something in the request url, headers, etc that I can use in my SP to determine who initiated the flow?

Answer (score 1):

If SP-initiated SSO flow was used, the SAML response has an attribute `InResponseTo`. This must be checked against the value of the `ID` attribute of the related SAML AuthnRequest.